# Populate android list with currently existing elements

Tags: android, listview

In my app I have to list the installed applications in a listview. App fetches the installed apps in a background thread.The requirement is that want to populate the the list eventhough the fetching is not completed.that is if there is one entry in the arraylist , show the arraylist with the that item. Is this possible?Please help me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is only possible when you use a loop for processing Application data in background. An outline:

Class to hold App information:

```
Class AppData {
  public final Drawable icon;
  public final String   name;

  public AppData(Drawable i, String n){
     this.icon = i;
     this.name = n;
  }    
}
```

AsynckTask to search Apps:

```
AsyncTask<Void,AppData,Void> scanAppsTask = new AsyncTask<Void,AppData,Void>{

  @Override
  public Void doInBackground(Void... args){

     //--get list---
     List<ApplicationInfo> apps = mPm.getInstalledApplications(
            PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES |
            PackageManager.GET_DISABLED_COMPONENTS);

     //--run a loop--
     for(ApplicationInfo appInfo : apps){

       AppData newFound;

       //---find app details, load app icon etc---

       publishProgress(newFound);

     }

     //---done---
     return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void onProgressUpdate(AppData... data){
    //---update list for every app found----
    myListAdapter.add(data[0]);
    myListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
}

scanAppsTask.execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

I was working on a similar app, where i need to fetch all the installed applications, even the built in applications. I have done this with the following code,

```
TextView data;
    ImageView image1;
    LinearLayout holdlayout;
    View l1;
    private ArrayList results = new ArrayList();
    List<ResolveInfo> list;
    TextView result;
    String str="";
    Drawable icon;
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
      {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            l1 = findViewById(R.id.Layout1);
        PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        list = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        for (ResolveInfo rInfo : list)
        {
            str = rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString() + "\n";
           results.add(rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
           Log.w("Installed Applications", rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString());
           icon =  rInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadIcon(pm);
           holdlayout = new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            holdlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            data = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
            data.setText(str);
            image1 = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
            image1.setBackgroundDrawable(icon);
            ((ViewGroup) holdlayout).addView(image1);
            ((ViewGroup) holdlayout).addView(data);
            ((ViewGroup) l1).addView(holdlayout);

        }
      }
```

Let me know, if you have any problem in this code.

Comment: I have a doubt.My background thread returns the entire list, not one by one.Then how can I populate the list

Comment: You can create a customized list adapter to populate the lkist.

Answer (score 1):

You can add/delete items to/from adapter of `ListView` dinamically, so yes you can populate list  with items one by one from background thread as soon as new item will available.